# Flutter - Will BLoC stream instances cause memory leak when a widget is closed?

Tags: dart, flutter, rxdart

There are some scenarios where screens with their respective BLoCs are frequently created and closed. So I'm somewhat concerned about memory safety of the Streams instances created in this process, because it doesn't seem they are disposed somewhere or whether they are GC-ed. This clearly depends on the specific implementation of DART libraries and flutter. So if you know about their behavior, please let me know.

These are some scenarios I have encountered.

1. Multi-tab browser-like application.
2. Navigation through screens. (But it's not that harmful.)
3. showDialog() senarios when there are BLoCs inside the dialog. This is a far more common senario. There could be a lot of dialog popping up frequently in an app.

I wonder if it is necessary to override dispose() function and explicitly close all streams in BLoCProvider. It seems existing tutorials didn't mention it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Streams will properly be cleaned as long as they aren't used anymore.
The thing is, to simply removing the variable isn't enough to unsure it's unused. It could still run in background.

You need to call `Sink.close()` so that it stops the associated `StreamController`, to ensure resources can later be freed by the GC.

To do that, you have to use `StatefulWidget.dispose` method:

```
abstract class MyBloc {
  Sink foo;
  Sink bar;
}

class MyWiget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyWigetState createState() => _MyWigetState();
}

class _MyWigetState extends State<MyWiget> {
  MyBloc bloc;

  @override
  void dispose() {
    bloc.bar.close();
    bloc.foo.close();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you think it's always better to use access a bloc via an interface than using a provider which effectively uses an inherited widget?

Comment: @stt106 What do you mean? An interface doesn't replace the provider, nor does the provider replace the interface

Comment: will chat to you on slack.

Comment: Oh, thanks. So it seems we need to close the Streams in the dispose() function. But there are some other problems with this solution. InheritedWidget has their own lifecycle. I'm not so sure about this, but is it likely that either user or flutter engine triggers an unintended disposal of InheritedWidget? Because I've seen in some tutorials that BLoCs becomes shared and InheritedWidget are created and re-assigned everywhere.

Comment: You need both an Inheritedwidget and a StatefulWidget

Comment: @RémiRousselet when I dispose then it's gone I go to another screen back to previous screen but the bloc is empty now

Comment: @rxlky You'll want to use `rxdart` and `BehaviorSubject`.

Comment: @RémiRousselet wow correct BehaviorSubject makes it appear again great, But there is a glitch when I swipe back to initial screen then log error says...."Bad state: Cannot add new events after calling close" however it is stll loaded. Any idea?

Comment: You called `close()` on the controller

Comment: @RémiRousselet sorry I don't get it. I don't have controller. It is actually tabbar which has its own stateful. I also tried calling init and dispose bloc from parent page also the same thing happens. Any idea?

Comment: Can you make it a question on its own? Comments isn't really the right place

Comment: @RémiRousselet it's ok I got the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52191451/bad-state-you-cannot-close-the-subject-while-items-are-being-added-from-addstre/52191587#comment95123235_52191587 I call await drain then everything ok