# What is the best way to close a Subject receiving a infinite Stream of data?

Tags: flutter, dart, rxdart

I have a problem on how to properly make a inifite stream of data to stop beeing added to a subject. Like the example below:

```dart
void main() async {
  var infinite = Stream.periodic(0.5.seconds, (it) => it);

  var subject = BehaviorSubject<int>();
  subject.addStream(infinite);

  subject.listen(print);
  await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 1000));
  await subject.close(); //It will not allow me to close the subject
}
```

The `infite` is a , well, infinite source of data. It will never emits a `close` event. So, how to properly close the `subject` since it will never finish to receive data?

Edit: the solution proposed on [Bad state: You cannot close the subject while items are being added from addStream in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52191451/bad-state-you-cannot-close-the-subject-while-items-are-being-added-from-addstre?rq=1) doesn't work simply because `drain` never returns.

Answer (score 4):

Don't use `addStream`.

You need a way to stop receiving events, and the `addStream` method does not provide any way to stop before the stream is done, which is never.

If you know *ahead of time* how many elements you want, you can do `subject.addStream(infinite.take(1000))` to only take the first 1000 events.

If not, perhaps it's like your example where you base it on time, then I'd go with something like:

```
var subscription = infinite.listen(subject.add);
subject.listen(print);
await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 100));
await subscription.cancel();
subject.close();
```

The `StreamSubscription` returned by `Stream.listen` gives you a way to *stop* listening again. Or to pause and later resume the events, if that's all you need.

If something else tells you when to stop, like the user clicking a button somewhere else, you either need to keep the subscription accessible so that you can call `cancel` on it at that later point from the code which knows that it's time to stop, or do so when the subject is cancelled:

```
var subscription = infinite.listen(subject.add);
subject.onCancel = subscription.cancel;
subject.listen(print);
```

Comment: Your answer is a nice strategy. But actually I don't know when to stop listening. Imagine that the user can leave the screen any time. What is the best strategy in this case?

Comment: Add more to the answer.